# Loop to find pre-determined sums

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

This might be a bit hard to explain...

In Oracle database (using SQL and PL/SQL), I have two tables.

Table A has invoices, with the total amount for the invoice.

Table B has individual invoice payments. There can be more than one payment record for each invoice.

Don't ask why, but for some reason the two tables do not have a link. There is no ID or referencing column. So there is no way for us to know what payments were for what invoice.

So, we are looking for a loop(s) process where we could pick an invoice amount on Table A and then lopp through and 'sum' various payments on Table B until we find a match.

So if the invoice amount is $150.00 on Table A, I want to find invoice payments that add up to $150.00 on Table B. Whether it is $40+$30+25+13+42, or whatever combination.

Does that make sense?

If so, what't the best way to do that?

Sample of tables as requested...

```
Table A      Table B
-------      -------
150          25
130          33
75           10.5
             27
             17
             87
             40
             10.5
             22
             17
             48
             18
```

Comment: What environment are you working in? What have you tried?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the tables? I would not recommend this approach as you may find multiple values adding to sum you are looking for, and what then?

For this type of operations I **strongly recommend**  familiarizing yourself with 2 essential libraries: **pandas** and **numpy**

Comment: Environment is Oracle database, using SQL, PL/SQL. I started writing some loops with inner loops but it started getting a bit confusing.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that this is a near impossible task to solve without some insanely large amount of processing. How large depends on the recordcount and your max allowable sample. Imagine a table with 100 records and you are allowed up to 5 invoice lines per invoice. That is something like 75,000,000 possible combinations. That number goes up dramatically as either number increases. A table with 1000 records with 10 allowable invoice lines per invoice is `263409560461970212832400` combinations

Comment: The permutations you have to check for each item in `table a` are `2^(COUNT(table b))` - this will add up quickly.

Comment: @JNevill yeah, that's pretty much what I assumed as well. I just figured I'd throw it out here in case someone had some clever solution.

Comment: I know the pain. I've been stuck with a similar situation trying to recover from a small number of records getting screwed up. I was able to guess my way through recovering a few since I had a few clues to go off of, but quickly gave up with the rest of them just because it was an insurmountable task.